# How do you transition from list view to a details view

Tags: wpf

How do I transition from a list view to a details view? For example, if I have a list of customers and I select one of the customers to go to that customer detail to view or change.

`List.xaml`
`Detail.xaml`

Comment: This question is very brief, and has been voted on accordingly. I was going to give this question the benefit of the doubt, since two answers have been given, so perhaps it is possible to work out what is being asked here. However the comment of "please help me with a proof of concept" is straying into the territory of asking for free work, so this can be closed as Needs Focus. Would you edit the question? Please add any research to it that you have done yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could for example use a `ContentControl` in the main window that binds to a property of the main view model that returns the view model of the view that you want to display, e.g.:

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentViewModel}">
    <ContentControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ListViewModel}">
            <local:List />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:DetailViewModel}">
            <local:Detail />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ContentControl.Resources>
</ContentControl>
```

Set the `CurrentViewModel` property of the main view model to an instance of a `ListViewModel` to display the `List` view and to a `DetailViewModel` to display the `Detail` view and make sure that the mian view model implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface correctly.

Comment: Can you please help me with a proof of concept

Comment: @Rod: I would urge you to give it a go yourself, and then edit the question with whatever you encounter on the way (as long as it does not change the thrust of the question too much).

Answer (score 2):

One pattern is to have the list and a detail pane side by side.

You can bind the parent of a panel containing the details controls to the selecteditem of your list.

Roughly:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ListBox x:Name="TheList"
             ItemsSource="{Binding DataCollection}">

    </ListBox>
    <StackPanel DataContext="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=TheList}"
                x:Name="DetailsView"
                >
        
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Side by side editing could look a bit like this:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/29859.wpf-tips-bind-to-current-item-of-collection.aspx

Which uses an alternative binding approach and / notation for the current item of a collectionview.

You could alternatively edit in a panel which is positioned on top of your list and made visible when the user selects an item to edit.

In that panel you can validate any edits and the user must explicitly commit valid edits or abandon invalid.

This is often combined with copying the data for the item being edited to a new item viewmodel so there are no complications with edits which fail validation. No need to revert because you commit valid changes by replacing the item being edited ( and writing changes to the database ).

Showing a full implementation is a fair bit of code but can end up looking something like:

[image]

The user edits in the panel.  Invalid data means the save/disk button is disabled and they can't save.  They can, however, still hit the quite/X button to abandon edits.

This is from a sample intended to show technique rather than a slick user experience. You'd probably want a bit more polish on your UI.

The various labels and textboxes or other controls are lined up using the technique explained here:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/29777.wpf-property-list-editing.aspx